# Android soket send but no receive from ESP8266

Tags: android, sockets, arduino, esp8266

My name is Carlos and it's been a couple of weeks that I want to implement connection with socket in my project but this is being hell for me. Communication is done through Android and an ESP8266 connected to a MEGA 2560 board, this board is running the DCC ++ EX.
After trying many examples I always get stuck in the same thing, I am unable to receive a response in time, it always takes around 4 minutes ... 4MINUTES !!! :(
I have tried Putty and other programs like Simple socket Test and it always connects well and receives responses.
I know it is a topic that has been talked about a lot but not even with the most up-to-date answers it receives correctly.
this class is inside the main Activity:

```
 @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public class WiFiSocketTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

        // Location of the remote host
        String address;
        int port;

        // Special messages denoting connection status
        private static final String PING_MSG = "SOCKET_PING";
        private static final String CONNECTED_MSG = "SOCKET_CONNECTED";
        private static final String DISCONNECTED_MSG = "SOCKET_DISCONNECTED";
        static final int IPTOS_RELIABILITY = 0x04;
        static final int IPTOS_LOWDELAY = 0x10;

        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        // Signal to disconnect from the socket
        private boolean disconnectSignal = false;

        // Socket timeout - close if no messages received (ms)
        private int timeout = 5000;

        // Constructor
        WiFiSocketTask(String address, int port) {
            this.address = address;
            this.port = port;
        }

        /**
         * Main method of AsyncTask, opens a socket and continuously reads from it
         */
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg) {

            try {

                // Open the socket and connect to it
                socket = new Socket();
//                socket = new Socket(address,port);
                socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(address, port), timeout);
                socket.setKeepAlive(true);
                socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                socket.setTrafficClass(IPTOS_LOWDELAY | IPTOS_RELIABILITY);
                // Get the input and output streams
                inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                outStream = socket.getOutputStream();

                // Confirm that the socket opened
                if (socket.isConnected()) {
                    publishProgress(CONNECTED_MSG);
                    disconnectSignal = false;

//                    // Make sure the input stream becomes ready, or timeout
//                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
//                    while(!inStream.ready()) {
//                        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
//                        if(now - start > timeout) {
//                            Log.e(TAG, "Input stream timeout, disconnecting!");
//                            disconnectSignal = true;
//                            break;
//                        }
//                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("WIFICLASS", "Socket did not connect!");
                    disconnectSignal = true;

                    // Once disconnected, try to close the streams
                    try {
                        if (socket != null) socket.close();
                        if (inStream != null) inStream.close();
                        if (outStream != null) outStream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    publishProgress(DISCONNECTED_MSG);
                }

                // Read messages in a loop until disconnected
                while (!disconnectSignal) {

                    // Parse a message with a newline character
                    String msg = inStream.readLine();

                    // Send it to the UI thread
                    publishProgress(msg);

                    Log.v("WIFICLASS", "[READLINE] " + msg);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("WIFICLASS", "Error in socket thread!");
                Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);
            }


            return null;
        }


         // This function runs in the UI thread but receives data from the
         // doInBackground() function running in a separate thread when
         //  publishProgress() is called.

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

            String msg = values[0];
            if (msg == null) return;

            // Handle meta-messages
            if (msg.equals(CONNECTED_MSG)) {
                //connected();
                new SaveConfig().GuardaRespuestaConexion(Scontext, true);
                MuestraComunicacionOut("Conectado con ip....");
                MuestraComunicacionIn(new SaveConfig().getWifiIp(Scontext) + ":"
                + new SaveConfig().getWifiPuerto(Scontext));

            } else if (msg.equals(DISCONNECTED_MSG)) {
                MuestraComunicacionIn("Desconectado");
            } else {// Invoke the gotMessage callback for all other messages
                MuestraSerialIn(msg);
                RespuestasCentral(msg);
            }
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


         // Write a message to the connection. Runs in UI thread.

        public void sendMessage(String data) {

            try {
                outStream.write(data.getBytes());
                outStream.flush();
                sleep(250);
                //outStream.write('\n');

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        // Set a flag to disconnect from the socket.

        public void disconnect() {
            disconnectSignal = true;
            try {
                if (socket != null) socket.close();
                if (inStream != null) inStream.close();
                if (outStream != null) outStream.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            publishProgress(DISCONNECTED_MSG);
        }

    }
```

I call the connection:

```
 public void ConectaWifi() {
    if(wifiTask != null) {
        MuestraComunicacionIn("Already connected!");
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Get the remote host from the UI and start the thread
        String host = "192.168.4.7";
        int port = 2560;

        // Start the asyncronous task thread
        MuestraComunicacionOut("Attempting to connect...");
        wifiTask = new WiFiSocketTask(host, port);
        wifiTask.execute();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        MuestraComunicacionOut("Invalid address/port!");
    }
```

This is what happens in the android studio log:

```
 11:34:46.899 D/AP-mensajeWIFI:: Attempting to connect...
 11:34:47.194 D/AP-mensajeWIFI:: Conectado con ip....
 11:34:47.194 D/AP-mensajeWIFI:: 192.168.4.12:8080
 11:34:50.699 D/AP-mensajeWIFI: Enviando: <1>
 11:38:08.972 D/AP-mensajeWifi: Respuesta: <p1>
```

And the Arduino IDE serial monitor

```
WiFi: [[CIPSEND=0,4]]\r\nOK\r\n>[XMIT 4]<p1> \r\nRecv 4 bytes\r\n\r\nSEND OK\r\n\r\n+IPD,0,3:
Wifi inbound data(0:3):<1>
Wifi EXEC: 0 3:<1>\0

WiFi: [[CIPSEND=0,4]]\r\nOK\r\n>[XMIT 4]<p1> \r\nRecv 4 bytes\r\n\r\nSEND OK\r\n0,CLOSED\r\n
```

Honestly I am alone in this I do not know or know of anyone who can help me or give me any advice on what to try. It's very frustrating...
Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: `// Confirm that the socket opened` Not needed. You can remove all code until the loop where you use readLine(). If readLine() returns null then stop.

Comment: You are never calling sendMessage().

Comment: `while (!disconnectSignal)` That is an endless loop as disconnectSignal can never change its value inside the loop.

Comment: `socket.connect(new... ` Too early. First do these settings. Put this just before opening the streams.